# Using the wrong php.ini file

Tags: php, windows, iis

I have installed php 5.6.0 locally on Windows 8.1 and IIS 8.5.9600.16384.

The php.ini file that I want it to use is in c:\php

My PHPRC environment variable is set to c:\php

Registry entries HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\5.6.0 > IniFilePath and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP > IniFilePath are also set to c:\php

php.exe is in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6

phpinfo gives me:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path    C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File            C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php.ini
```

I have restarted IIS

My "path" environment variable contains C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6;

I have added c:\php; to the "path" environment variable

I have rebooted my pc

What do I have to do to get it to use the php.ini in c:\php ?

EDIT:
After Ryan's suggestion of renaming the offending file, I now get:

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    PHP_via_FastCGI
Error Code     0x80070003
Requested URL      http://10.21.4.3:80/test/phpinfo.php
Physical Path      C:\IIS_Emea\WebRoot\Site01\test\phpinfo.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

Comment: to debug this i would rename the _php.ini_ in the _'5.6'_ directory to _php.orig_ini_. Then see what happens...

Comment: ok tried that and restarted iis - now I get an internal server error - I guess you could call that "getting somewhere" :-)

Comment: drat! - Is there a shortcut to php.exe that has the 'ini file' hard coded in it? From the command line do: _php --ini_ - it will show you where it finds the ini file. try this in the _c:\php, c:\  and the '5.6'_  directories. I would expect the first two to show what you expect.

Comment: in all of those folders I get c:\php\php.ini - so all is good from the cli

Comment: I run it from a browser

Comment: No - i mean you need to check the web-server settings to ensure it uses the correct php settings. alas, i don't use IIS.

Comment: ok this question has moved onto "how do I change the configuration file path in php manager in iis", but thanks for getting me to this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uninstalled php and installed it manually instead.  Now I have more control, a better understanding and a working php 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had Wampserver installed and then switched to nginx, so Wampserver was still holding php. I was expecting it to be using `c:\nginx\php\` but it was using `c:\wamp64\php`.

A person can check by typing into the CLI: `which php`. That works on Windows and will show the used location.